# Check if the string is of type T in C++11

Tags: c++, string, types

Is there a standard library function to check that a string S is of type T and therefore can be converted to a variable of type T?

I know there is istringstream STL class that can, using operator>>, fill a variable of type T with a value converted from string. However, it will be filled with nonesense if the string content did not have the format of type T.

Comment: `it will be filled with nonesense if the string content did not have the format of type T.` That's because it is uninitialized.

Comment: Strings don't have types. The best you can do is guess, using something like [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best you can do is try and fail, as @Cameron commented:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template <typename T>
boost::optional<T> convert(std::string const & s)
{
    T x;
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    if (iss >> x >> std::ws && iss.get() == EOF) { return x; }
    return boost::none;
}
```

Or, without boost:

```
template <typename T>
bool convert(std::string const & s, T & x)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    return iss >> x >> std::ws && iss.get() == EOF;
}
```

Usage:

- First version:

  ```
  if (auto x = convert<int>(s))
  {
      std::cout << "Read value: " << x.get() << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "Invalid string\n";
  }
  ```
- Second version:

  ```
  {
      int x;
      if (convert<int>(s, x))
      {
          std::cout << "Read value: " << x << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << "Invalid string\n";
      }
  }
  ```

Note that `boost::lexical_cast` is basically a cleverer version of this, which claims to be very efficient (potentially moreso than using iostreams unconditionally as we did here).

Comment: Succinct and correct. i doubt the OP will understand without further explanation (especially the latter, which seems... too trivial if you don't read closely :))

Comment: This will succeed with a string like "123abc" converted to `int`, which is usually not what people will expect.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard library function. To see if it was successful, you are supposed to check the return from `operator>>`:

```
std::istringstream iss(mystring);

// if you want trailing whitespace to be invalid, remove std::ws
if((iss >> myT >> std::ws) && iss.eof())
{
   // success
}
else
{
   // failed
}
```

Comment: I thought that streams convert to 'true' if they are ok.

Comment: This will fail on a string with trailing whitespace (Might be what OP wants).

Comment: @jrok: Yes, you probably want to discard whitespace in most situations (edited).